# Altair Annotation from a List

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I have a graph that looks like this: [image: original]

And would like to add annotations to make it look like this:
[image]

Is there a way to add these annotations from a dataframe with the annotation text?

```
annotations = [['2017-08-27 00:15:00',4, 'Fight begins'],
           ['2017-08-27 00:22:00',5, 'McGregor does OK \nin the early rounds'],
           ['2017-08-27 00:53:00',4, 'Mayweather takes \nover and wins by \nTKO']]
           a_df = pd.DataFrame(annotations, columns=['date','count','note'])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any automatic way to do that in Altair.

What is possible is to add a text layer; for example:

```
text = alt.Chart(annotations).mark_text().encode(
  x='date:Q',
  y='count:N',
  text='note:N',
)

chart = lines + text
```

But this will simply draw blocks of text at the specified locations; it won't add annotation arrows or do any sort of automatic placement, wrapping, or collision avoidance. In the current version of Altair, you'll have to do that manually.